# Switching off the AC before turning off the engine to increase longevity - urban myth?

Tags: engine, ac

I was riding with a friend and he insisted that it's better for me to switch off the AC before turning off the engine because when you turn on the car the AC won't get switched on with it and the engine won't have the load from the AC and thus will have a longer life.

Is there any truth to this claim or is this an urban myth?

OR

Perhaps this used to be true with older cars, but not anymore with modern designs?

*Note: by AC I mean cooling exclusively, not heating. I live in a hot country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that leaving the AC on while starting the vehicle would be harder on the starter motor rather than the engine.

I say Urban Myth....but, who am I to disagree with your friend...